# How to stretch font to TextBox size?

Tags: .net, xaml

Any clue how to stretch TextBox font size automatically?

Thank you!

```
<Grid Name="DigitalClock" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <TextBlock Name="dClock" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ViewBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) which will stretch the content to fit.